# Coronavirus conspiracy theory (HIV biological weapon)

Tags: virus, covid-19

There's a ridiculous conspiracy theory spreading that coronavirus is a genetically modified biological weapon gone rogue. According to one theory, the virus has traces of HIV and is designed to attack the immune system. My question isn't related to the evidence, which is non-existent, supporting this theory but rather the science behind the claim.

HIV can only spread via blood, semen, pre-seminal fluids, rectal fluids, vaginal fluids, and breast milk. Is it even conceivable that an "HIV like" virus could spread through the air like coronavirus? The conspiracy theory isn't saying you will get full-blown AIDS but that coronavirus can "attack the immune system" (in a way mimicking HIV). I'm not a doctor, but on the surface, the claim that a virus could even somewhat operate like HIV and be airborne sounds absurd.

Several scientists have already said there's no way coronavirus DNA was engineered, but I'm looking for another angle to attack this conspiracy theory.

"There's absolutely nothing in the genome sequence of this virus that indicates the virus was engineered," Richard Ebright, a professor of chemical biology at Rutgers University, told The Washington Post Sunday.

https://www.businessinsider.com/coronavirus-bioweapon-tom-cotton-conspiracy-theory-china-warfare-leak-2020-2

Comment: I applaud your efforts to counter the fear mongers and conspiracy theorists, but this sort of question isn't a very good fit for the format here. Asking for a better argument is always going to be a matter of opinion. And, really, how do you get better than citing credible experts who've spoken out on the issue?

Answer (score 3):

I somewhat agree that it's difficult to debunk conspiracy theories, as people that believe in them can and usually will reply to carefully crafted arguments with "of course that's fabricated too".

Having said that, I came across this: [The Proximal Origin of SARS-CoV-2](http://virological.org/t/the-proximal-origin-of-sars-cov-2/398)

It discusses the origins for this virus. Hope you find it useful.